# How to make my html launch right away, not in "Index Of" directory?[html]

Tags: html, web, directory, hosting

I want my html file to launch right away when on start, but now it shows me this:

[image: ddd]

I use free webhosting, how do I make it main file, or root file that actually gets launched when visiting my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up about the [.htaccess file](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess6.shtml).

You can set your DirectoryIndex to any file you want.

Comment: thank you all! But this answer also revealed to me some details on ht access file

Answer (score 2):

Try renaming the file erjan_sample.html to index.html.

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming the file erjan_sample.html to index.html/Default.html

Answer (score 0):

Rename your .html as "index.html"

Answer (score 0):

Just change the name of your root site to index.html